# write a function with tolerance

Tags: function, parameters

Say you have a function with three float parameters and you are asked to return true if the first two are close enough in value to each other. "Close enough" is defined as +/- the third parameter of each other and that is what is known as tolerance. How do you go about making a parameter with tolerance?

Comment: The smells like a homework problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: well i created a function def assertAlmostEqual (float() and i know that it needs an if statement to return a true if the tolerance is met and if not it should return false... but im not sure if i should make something like (A,B,C) and say a statement like if A<=B<=C? Im quite bad at this i apologize if it was a stupid question. @dan08